# Missing } inserted \end{center} i got this error while running following code

Tags: horizontal-alignment

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
{\normalsize{A Dissertation on}}\\
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}
\vspace{5mm} 
{\Large\bf  {{Fractional Order Controller}}} \\
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}
\vspace{8mm}
{\normalsize{J.A.Gaikwad }} \\
\vspace{8mm}
{\normalsize\bf{Vishwakarma Institute of Technology, Pune}} \\
{\normalsize\textit{(An Autonomous Institute Affiliated to University of Pune)}}\\
\vspace{5mm}
{\normalsize{in partial fulfillment of the requirements for the award of the degree }} \\
%{\normalsize{for the degree of}} \\

\vspace{5mm}
{\Large\bf{Master of Engineering}} \\
%\normalsize{(M. Tech)}\\
\vspace{2mm}
{\normalsize{in}} \\
\vspace{2mm}
{\Large{Instrumentation and Control}} \\
{\large{(Process Instrumentation)}} \\
\vspace{4mm}
{\normalsize{by}} \\

\vspace{4mm}
{\Large\bf{Priyanka Wadje} \\
\vspace{1mm}
\normalsize{(GR NO. 13M089)} \\


\vspace{10mm}
{\large{Under the guidance of}} \\

\vspace{3mm}
{\Large\bf{J.A.Gaikwad}} \\

\vspace{10mm}
\includegraphics[width=1.25in]{vitlogo1.eps}\\%[.5in]
\vspace{15mm}
{\large \bf {Department of Instrumentation and Control Engineering}}\\
%\vspace{1mm}
{\large \bf {Vishwakarma Institute of Technology, Pune-411037}}\\

\vspace{3mm}
\large \bf {31 July 2014}
\end{center}
```

Comment: The opening brace at line 33 (before `\Large`) isn't closed. And I don't understand why you are using braces after `\bf`. This control sequence isn't a macro with parameter. This is very often mistake of LaTeX users.

Comment: should i add comment directly without using braces

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using `\normalsize`, `\large`, and `\Large` properly: they act as switches and affect everything in the current scope, not just the material in the subsequent `{ ... }` brace group. The macro `\bf` isn't fully supported under LaTeX (it's a Plain-TeX command); use `\bfseries` instead. The instruction `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}` isn't working the way you're using it. I suggest you load the `setspace` package and issue the command `\setstretch{1.1}` instead. Finally, I would add the instruction `\thispagestyle{empty}` to the page in question, as title pages typically do not show a page number.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % choose margins suitably
\usepackage{setspace}  % for '\setstretch' macro
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\setstretch{1.1}
A Dissertation on\\
\vspace{5mm} 
{\Large\bfseries  Fractional Order Controller} \\
\vspace{8mm}
J.A. Gaikwad\\
\vspace{8mm}
{\bfseries Vishwakarma Institute of Technology, Pune} \\
({\itshape An Autonomous Institute Affiliated to University of Pune})\\
\vspace{5mm}
in partial fulfillment of the requirements for the award of the degree \\
%{\normalsize{for the degree of}} \\

\vspace{5mm}
{\Large\bfseries Master of Engineering} \\
%\normalsize{(M. Tech)}\\
\vspace{2mm}
in \\
\vspace{2mm}
{\Large Instrumentation and Control } \\
{\large (Process Instrumentation) } \\
\vspace{4mm}
by \\

\vspace{4mm}
{\Large\bfseries Priyanka Wadje} \\
\vspace{1mm}
(GR NO. 13M089) \\


\vspace{10mm}
{\large Under the guidance of} \\

\vspace{3mm}
{\Large\bfseries J.A. Gaikwad} \\

\vspace{10mm}
\includegraphics[width=1.25in]{vitlogo1.eps}\\%[.5in]
\vspace{15mm}
{\large \bfseries Department of Instrumentation and Control Engineering}\\
%\vspace{1mm}
{\large \bfseries Vishwakarma Institute of Technology, Pune-411037}\\

\vspace{3mm}
{\large \bfseries 31 July 2014}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: again i got same error

Comment: i run the code given by you, even i got same error

Comment: @user68949 - what's the error message, on which line does it occur, and which TeX distribution are you running? (I get no error or warning messages when running this code with MacTeX2014.)